# Boilerplate for creating Android native modules for React Native

Tags: android, react-native

Is there an accepted boilerplate for creating native Android modules to use in React Native applications. A few problems that I have encountered when creating a native Android modules:

1. There is no suggested boilerplate for the native module. So, I just copy some native module project and remove all the project specific code and keep the rest which mainly included some gradle and properties file but I am always worried if it doesn't contain some required files or it contains some project specific settings which will interfere with my module etc.
2. The project never successfully builds in Android studio because it is not able to find any of the facebook packages which are required to be imported in order to create the native module. So, I end up writing the code in the module. Import the module in my main app. Build the android project for the main app in Android Studio and fix any compilation errors. Is that the usual way of creating the native module or is it possible to at least build the native module itself in Android Studio successfully
3. This is a little bit unrelated but there is a build.gradle file for all the native modules and one for my `app` module as well which have similar settings. Does the `app` build.gradle file overrides the other native modules build.gradle files and is used to build all the native modules or each native module built as per its own build.gradle file

Please share your thoughts/insights on any/all of the above. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to react-native, and I initially had the same problem of not knowing how to generate Android/iOS Native Modules.

I saw them in other example codes and at first tried to copy them and clean them up, but I knew/felt-like I was doing something wrong.

Then I went back and noticed in this doc (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html) that there is both a "Quick Start" tab and [what you want] a "Building Projects with Native Code" tab.

That "Building Projects with Native Code" tab tells you to `react-native init AwesomeProject`, which is the secret sauce for generating boilerplate Android and iOS Native Modules.

Being new to this, I am still looking for an option to generate Android/iOS boilerplate both with and **without** BUCK support.

Comment: Doesn't this create an application though?  What if I want to create a module as a separate entity rather than adding a native module directly into an application?  All the tutorials I've found so far suggest using `react-native new-library`, but this only seems to generate boilerplate for iOS, not Android.  Is there an Android equivalent?